# Stdout logging for ASP.NET Core 3.1 in plesk panel create file but it's size is 0 and its empty

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, plesk

stdout logging for ASP.NET Core 3.1 in plesk panel create file but it's size is 0 and its empty.

I enabled stdout log in ASP.NET Core 3.1 application in plesk panel and it is working and created file of log but the log file is empty and it is 0B

I get an http 502 error and I can not find the problem.